# Migrate data between tables efficiently

Tags: performance, php, symfony2

I wrote a very simple quick and easy script to migrate a bunch of data to another table in my database.

Can I accomplish this task without using so many foreach loops?
I realize I'm imputting *similar* data in each of my loops and it just seems redundant and wrong.

I thought of using `array_merge` on `talkers, pros & anons` and I thought that   because each of the second loops use the same field, I would write code to retrieve `getYI` and then write code to determine if it belonged to a `talker, anon, or pro`.
However I wasn't sure if either of those solutions would make my script any more efficient/better.

Certainly any insight would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

And if it helps I'm using Symfony 2.3.

```
public function migratingDataScript()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $talkers = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Talker')->findAll();
    $anons = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Anon')->findAll();
    $pros = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Pro')->findAll();

    foreach ($talkers as $talker) {
        echo "Talker: ".$talker->getId()."<br>";
        foreach ($talker->getYI() as $year => $status) {
            $rounds = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Round')->findByYear($year);
            foreach ($rounds as $round) {
                $newTalkerInvitation = new Invitation($round);
                $newTalkerInvitation->setStatus($status);
                $newTalkerInvitation->setTalker($talker);
                // $newTalkerInvitation->setNumAt(); No Data For Talker
                // $newTalkerInvitation->setStart(); No Data For Talker
                $em->persist($newTalkerInvitation);
            }
        }
    }//Ends Talker Migration

    foreach ($anons as $anon) {
        echo "Anon: ".$anon->getId()."<br>";
        foreach ($anon->getYI() as $year => $status) {
            $rounds = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Round')->findByYear($year);
            foreach ($rounds as $round) {
                $newAnonInvitation = new Invitation($round);
                $newAnonInvitation->setStatus($status);
                $newAnonInvitation->setAnon($anon);
                // $newAnonInvitation->setNumAt(); No Data For Anon
                // $newAnonInvitation->setStart(); No Data For Anon
                $em->persist($newAnonInvitation);
            }
        }
    }//Ends Anon Migration

    foreach ($pros as $pro) {
        echo "Pro: ".$pro->getId()."<br>";
        foreach ($pro->getYI() as $year => $status) {
            $rounds = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Round')->findByYear($year);
            foreach ($rounds as $round) {
                $newProInvitation = new Invitation($round);
                $newProInvitation->setStatus($status);
                $newProInvitation->setPro($pro);
                if(is_null($pro->getNumOfAttempts())){
                    $newProInvitation->setNumAt('0');
                }else {
                    $newProInvitation->setNumAt($pro->getNumOfAttempts());
                }
                // $newProInvitation->setStart(); No Data For Pro
                $em->persist($newProInvitation);
            }
        }
    }//Ends Pro Migration

    $em->flush();
    echo "Completed.";
    die;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you take a look at iterate() (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-results) instead of findAll(). This can save you a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I accomplish this task without using so many foreach loops?

Depends.

If you want to stick with database-agnostic abstraction such as Doctrine, there is no way to avoid loops.

But if you want an *efficient* solution, you can write a database-specific query to copy all records in a single query. For example, for mysql it would be something like

```
INSERT INTO invitation (field1, field2, status, talker) 
  SELECT field1, field2, ?, ? FROM talker
```

and then bind $status and $talker to this query.